# Android Studio Run button does nothing

Tags: android, android-studio

Upon creating a brand new android app; I click the run button, and it sits there and does absolutely nothing. I'm assuming an issue with Gradle possibly as the only thing remotely close to an error is the "Gradle Sync" warning me:

Warning:The project encoding (windows-1252) does not match the encoding specified in the Gradle build files (UTF-8).
This can lead to serious bugs.

Would this preclude me from being able to do anything? I've had an android app running on here before a few months ago with no issues like this, so I'm not even sure what to check.

Comment: Click on any file belonging to your project and then click Run.

Comment: Can you share a full screenshot of your full Android Studio window?

Comment: If nothing is selected, nothing will run.

Comment: Here is a link to what I'm looking at [http://pasteboard.co/1lq7qN7V.jpg](http://pasteboard.co/1lq7qN7V.jpg) I've tried selecting the project and Run; I've tried right-clicking the activity and Run; I've tried syncing Gradle (which displays no errors after switching all to UTF-8)

Comment: Here is another image of the gradle console [http://pasteboard.co/1lqopnRS.jpg](http://pasteboard.co/1lqopnRS.jpg)

Answer (score 12):

Possible Soluions:

1. In AndroidStudio  goto files->InvalidateCachesAndRestart
2. Try sync product with Gradle.
3. Once the Run button is green with App selected. Then give Run

To check if some background process is running on pressing the Run button, click on the GradleConsole on the bottom right corner of your Android Studio.

Comment: I had the exact same issue. Click the run button, it builds successfully but never installs on the device. I had to disable the `HMS Toolkit` Plugin for run to work as expected! ```Android Studio > Preferences > Plugins```
My Hms Toolkit was on `6.3.0.3003AF`

Comment: @Francois Thank you so much, the run worked fine after disabling the HMS Toolkit.

Answer (score 7):

I was facing the same issue (Click the run button and nothing happens). After digging into AndroidStuido I tried going to SDK Manager and installed the suggested install packages (shows in install button with 'Install (1) Package') .after installing that now I am able to run my app...

I think some SDK was not up to date or might not installed properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try close and reopen the Android Studio once. It worked for me I don't know how

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I had to delete the virtual device and recreate it in the Studio. Somehow the device itself (or the control software in there) had confused itself.

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't figure out what setting to change, a simple and complete uninstall and reinstall seems to have fixed it. >.>

Answer (score 0):

I also into trap of this green RUN button in Android studio.  Whenever I clicked it and select device for ADB , it is doing nothing. On checking Gradle event log tab in Android Studio(at bottom  right corner , in left of gradle console tab), error was `EmptyThrowable: Runner Run is not registered`. 
How I solve it temporarily: Use Debug App option on right of RUN button(shift + F9). It did start the build  process and I saved my time.

Or you can check your adb cosole for logs places in bottom right corner of Android Studio. If it says missing adb location in sdk, try to lauch sdk manager and update platfor-tools for latest version. This will fix missing adb file in sdk.

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to location in *C:\Program files\Android\Android Studio\bin\idea.properties*

2.Open the **idea.properties** file via any text editor

3.Add the following code to `disable.android.first.run=true`

4.Save as file on desktop

5.Go to the *C:\Program files\Android\Android Studio\bin*

6.Paste the file which we save as on desktop

7.Now replace **idea.propeties** file.

Done...!

Answer (score 0):

close the android studio..

Open this link...

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html#tos-header

and download platform-tools extracted it

and then paste these platform form tools into

C:\Users\Faisal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\

replace existing tools with new one

open the android studio now it work fine...

Answer (score 0):

If you recently cleared your settings cache, you may need to reset your Run/Debug Configurations:

Run > Edit Configurations > Android App > app (from left menu) >

Deployment Target Options: Target Emulator

Preferred Android Virtual Device: < emulator target you created, e.g. Pixel 2 API 28>

[image: Select Run/Debug Configurations from Menu]

[image: Choose Configurations]

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was "not enough space" issue. Required 7GB of free space on C: and I had only 3

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because I did not have VT-x / Intel Virtualization Technology enabled in my BIOS. Flipping that after a machine restart and trying to run in Android Studio again worked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by doing Help->CheckForUpdates about 4 times (I did not install the beta).  Which required a couple downloads and a couple restarts.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,run button was visible in green color but nothing happened on clicking it

I opened another project and it worked there normally

All was working fine,I could install build apks smoothly and suddenly this issue occured

Sync Project with Gradle Files/Sync/Rebuild/Make/Restart/End task
nothing worked

Even copied project to another project but same issue

Invented a quick hack for temporory basis

[image]

Just go to Build Tab > find the installDebug task and click to run it

The app will be built and installed

Just launch manually from launcher